# Two way to address an excel worksheet but index numbers are different

Tags: excel, worksheet, vba

I'm using Excel 2016 VBA to get to a worksheet entitled Sheet40 (TestRandomTeams).
Both the following 2 lines of code point to the same worksheet, but I don't understand WHY?

```
Application.Goto ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(45).Cells(6, 5)

Worksheets(40).Activate
```

There is only one workbook open.

Comment: Are the two lines of code used without any modification of the order of the sheet tabs occurring between when the two lines are executed, and without any addition or deletion of sheets between them?

Comment: Both lines are together. One after another.

Sheet40 is TESTMakeRandomTeams

Application.Goto ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(45).Cells(6, 5)

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(40).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TESTMakeRandomTeams").Select

Comment: Do you have an event in worksheets(45) that might be selecting worksheets(40) (e.g. in its `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event)?

Comment: In an Immediate Window, enter the command `?Worksheets(40).Name & "|" & Worksheets(45).Name` and see what is displayed.

Comment: WK #5C|TESTMakeRandomTeams
Sheet property window shows the same.
I will check on events in ws-45.

Comment: No Events that I can see. I did have a macro to load a visual index on workbook open. Is there a way to detect all events being executed?
Would a screenshot of VBA window help?

Comment: Based on what you see in the Immediate Window, `Worksheets(40)` is the one named "WK #5C", so that is the one that might be somehow redirecting the selection to `Worksheets(45)` (which is the one you appear to want to use because it is named "TESTMakeRandomTeams" and appears to have a `CodeName` of `Sheet40`).  Remember that the **index of `Worksheets`** simply refers to the tab order in which the sheets appear (left to right), the **`CodeName`** is a name assigned by the VBE (but can be modified using the VBE), and the **`Name`** is what appears on the tab (e.g. "TestMakeRandomTeams").

Comment: A screenshot of the Project Explorer window within VBA might assist (especially if you can get it to show **all** the worksheets that you have) and the code from the code module of the "WK #5C" worksheet might also help.

Comment: Don't know how to add screenshots

Comment: My error is thinking that Sheet40 is the same as sheet index 40.
Code has been corrected.
I have so much to learn.
Thanks for your help!, YowE3K